# How do I implement an ActionListener with custom constructor?

Tags: java, actionlistener

I need to implement an action listener with a custom constructor so that I can pass parameter to it.

```
     class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public ActionListener(int u){

        }



        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        }
    }
```

but It seems I can't override constructors.How do I do it?

Comment: name the constructor CustomActionListener and remove the override annotation

Comment: Ha ha,thanks,Seems like I'm a bit tired that I couldn't even remember this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActionListener is an interface, there is no constructor in it.

More over you can not override constructors. In extended class constructor, you need to call super constructor if no default constructor is there in **super class**.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call super class constructor before anything else. Sounds simple to me if that's what you mean:

```
public class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener{

    private int u;

    public CustomActionListener(int u) {
        super();
        this.u = u;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```